# Wheel rotation with audio in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my app there is a spinning wheel. I am using `KeyFrameAnimations` and I want to add sound effects to the wheel rotation animation.

I tried `AVAudioPlayer` but I want the audio speed to change with the speed of wheel rotation. Please help me!

Comment: I tried AVAudioPlayer. But I want the audio speed to change with the speed of wheel rotation.

Comment: `player.rate=2.0f;` and `player.enableRate=YES;` did not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
YourPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:YourPath] error:&err];

// enable adjustable playback rate for an audio player
YourPlayer.enableRate=YES; 
// for playback speed: 0.5 half speed, 1.0 normal, 2.0 double speed
YourPlayer.rate=2.0f;
[YourPlayer prepareToPlay];
[YourPlayer play];
```

Check this apple documentation, [AVAudioPlayer Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/rate)

I think you can change the `.rate` during playback. 
About the syncing to the rotation of your wheel, it's up to you how to implement that, maybe a work around (using `NSTimer` that is fired accordingly to sync the rotation will do).

Anyway hope this helps you, Cheers! :)